# AngularJS ng-select issue

Tags: angularjs

I've got a simple page selector I'm using in an Angular 1.5 page.  The select works for the most part, but the ng-selected part does not.

If I'm on page 3, (which is ironically the last page, not sure if that matters) 3 is selected by default.  If I'm on page 1 or 2, the first item (blank) is selected.  I'm not super versed in Javascript, but figured it might be a type issue.  Tried settings $scope.thisPage with parseInt(page) and page.toString() just in case it did something under the sheets I wasn't aware of, but it all turned out the same.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$route','$routeParams', function($scope,$route,$routeParams) {
    $scope.pages = [];
    var page = $routeParams.p ? $routeParams.p : 1
    $scope.thisPage = page; 
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.pages.push(i);
    }
}]);

<form name="myForm">
    <select ng-model="selectedPage" ng-change="switchPage(selectedPage)">
    <option ng-repeat="p in pages" ng-value="{{p}}" ng-selected="{{p == thisPage}}">{{p}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need no set selected property

```
<form name="myForm">
    <select ng-model="selectedPage" ng-change="switchPage(selectedPage)">
    <option ng-repeat="p in pages" ng-value="{{p}}">{{p}}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Instead bind the selectedPage value with thisPage

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$route','$routeParams', function($scope,$route,$routeParams) {
    $scope.pages = [];
    var page = $routeParams.p ? $routeParams.p : 1
    $scope.selectedPage= page; ////////////////////////////////
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.pages.push(i);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: What if he has a reason to use ng-selected ? However, that's correct too :)

Comment: why to use ngSelected when you are having two way data binding

Comment: If there is no point on stocking the value and it's only used for display with proper styling ?
Who are we to judge :D

Comment: Thanks so much -- this worked.  I could have sworn I tried this earlier (I tried a few solutions, but most were for fancier models).  Anywho, on to the next problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

ngSelected require an expression as following `p == thisPage` and not `{{p == thisPage}}`

Source : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: this gives me the same results. :(

Comment: @kiss-o-matic oh... Could you create a plunker or codepen with your project ? It helps debugging :)